# Could a solar thermopile be enough to power a small satellite?

Tags: artificial-satellite, power, solar-power

[It seems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermocouple#Power_production) that a nuclear thermoelectric generator was used to power spacecrafts for some exploration missions. Can a thermopile that harvest the light/shade temperature difference on Earth's orbit be used to power a small satellite? What about a Mercury satellite, would it be more reliable and efficient than solar panels which could melt on those conditions?

Comment: [MESSENGER](http://messenger.jhuapl.edu/)'s solar panels haven't melted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no theoretical reason why not.  The main reason why they aren't used is practical: the best solar panels convert about 22% of available energy to electricity, while the best thermoelectric generators operate at about 8% of Carnot efficiency, which for a reasonable temperature gradient works out to converting about 4% of available energy.